# Press button and go to random view in iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 32 different views in my iPhone app, and when the user presses a button, I need the view to change to either of the 32 views randomly. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Set an array with all the views in it.

```
NSArray *viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1,view2....,nil];
```

Second when the user taps the button get one of the views with:

```
- (UIView*) getRandomView {
  int rand = arc4random_uniform([viewsArray count]);
  UIView *selectedView = [viewsArray objectAtIndex:rand];
  return selectedView;
}
```

Lastly add the returned view as a subview:

```
-(void)userTappedTheButton{
   [self.view addSubView:[self getRandomView]];
}
```

Comment: Please, can you explain me detail? because I am very new for ios development. Thanks